# How to send video using Gstreamer to another computer on a different network

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, gstreamer

I want send video using GStreamer to another computer with a different network.

Example pipeline, using webcam:

Updated pipelines:

Server

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=IP port=PORT
```

Client

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=PORT ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

So the problem isn't with Gstreamer, but with the ip's of the computers that doesn't have the same network.

I would like to get a way, maybe web-based or anything else to help me send the videos between 2 different networks.

I don't want to use VPN and I have full access to both of the computers/network (client and server).

thanks

Comment: Your example pipelines look from very old gstreamer version. Please give the version (you may use gst-launch or gst-launch-1.0 with flag --version for getting it). Also there are multiple protocols for sending video over network. You would tell more your case (available codecs and their performance on your platform, expected latency, image quality, network topology, ...) for better advice.

Comment: Also provide details about available formats from your camera. `v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --list-formats-ext` (v4l2-ctl command may be provided by installing package `v4l-utils`)

Comment: @SeB, It is just an example that I took from another place. I changed it but it's not really relevant to my question.

Comment: what are the platforms for sender and receiver ? What are the available formats of camera on sender side ? And what is network between these ?

Comment: @SeB again it's not relevant. the question is not mainly asked about gstreamer, but about what IP should I send to the receiver if they aren't on the same network and without VPN. public IP or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Using H264 encoding into MPEG2 TS would indeed allow using RTP/MP2T that has static payload (33).
On sender side you may add these properties to x264enc:

```
... ! x264enc insert-vui=1 key-int-max=30 ! ...
```

That should be easily viewed by VLC without SDP file:

```
cvlc rtp://127.0.0.1:<PORT>
```

For reading it from gstreamer, you would use something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=<IP> port=<PORT> ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=MP2T,clock-rate=90000,payload=33 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=300 ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Comment: you didn;t really understand my question, if you know the IP and port for example using VPN is easy to use GStreamer, but I want to do it without VPN. Do I need to use public IP or something like that? how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to use webrtc for this, because that will take care of port mapping through NAT on both sides.